# What are the differences between Consumer committableSource and plainSource?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, alpakka

I am trying to use the consumer library https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/consumer.html the method `committableSource` as the following:

```
 Consumer
    .committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("SAP-EVENT-BUS"))
    .map(_.committableOffset)
    .toMat(Committer.sink(committerSettings))(Keep.both)
    .mapMaterializedValue(DrainingControl.apply)
    .run()
```

The problem here is, how to get the messages, that the consumer receives from `Kafka`?

With the following code snippet works:

```
  Consumer
    .plainSource(
      consumerSettings,
      Subscriptions.topics("SAP-EVENT-BUS"))
    .to(Sink.foreach(println))
    .run()
```

The whole code snippet:

```
private implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  private val config = context.system.settings.config.getConfig("akka.kafka.consumer")
  private val consumerSettings =
    ConsumerSettings(config, new StringDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
      .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
      .withGroupId("SAP-SENDER-GROUP")
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")

  private val committerSettings = CommitterSettings(context.system)

  Consumer
    .committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("TOPIC"))
    .map(_.committableOffset)
    .toMat(Committer.sink(committerSettings))(Keep.both)
    .mapMaterializedValue(DrainingControl.apply)
    .run()

  Consumer
    .plainSource(
      consumerSettings,
      Subscriptions.topics("SAP-EVENT-BUS"))
    .to(Sink.foreach(println))
    .run()
```

Or do I have to use both, one for commit and another for consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Committer.sink`, which terminates the stream, use `Committer.flow` which allows you to continue the stream until you choose to terminate it with a different sink.